# how outlook 2013 plugin development in java technology?

Tags: java, c#, .net, outlook-addin

How can I create a plugin(Attachment extractor ) for outlook?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18322/How-to-Create-Outlook-AddIN-Plugin

I found that it is possible with .Net but I want to develop it in Java. Are there any attachment extractors for outlook? All I have found have been in .NET.

Comment: Trust me, it would be a lot easier for you to learn C# (which is not that different from Java) than try to fit a square peg into a round hole by writing the addin in Java. Language is just a tool, it is easy. Learning the API is hard.

Answer (score 0):

It is up to you which programming language is to choose for developing an Office add-in. You just need to implement the [IDTExtensibility2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/extensibility.idtextensibility2.aspx) interface. To get it loaded by Office applications you have to add the required windows registry keys, see [Registry Entries for Application-Level Add-Ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx) for more information.

If you choose to go with C# (VSTO), see [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx).